# Graphics get cut for long tag labels

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the list of my favorite tags (column at the right of the main page), when I include a tag with a long name, the graphics for the tags are cut and missing their rightmost part (almost all of them, not only the longest one):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're rolling out a new look to Stack Exchange sites that are in their beta phase - [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) is the first to receive it.

This bug is fixed in the new design, so just wait a bit :)